# Looking for job while working as intern?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, internship

I am student in my final year and during the last summer I had an internship with a great company, say company X, which turned into a part time job while I am still in school. I get the general feeling that company X is interested in keeping me on, especially since they are allowing me to work remotely from school. I really enjoy this line of work so far but I am unsure that company X has projects that I would enjoy doing as a career(i.e. something related to my graduate degree).

My question is: Would it be uncouth of me to look at different companies to work for once I graduate in the spring? Did I make some sort of a non-verbal commitment to company X by seeking part time employment during the school year?

I understand that I am my own person and at any time I am free to work where I please but, since I am new to the job market I do not want to kick things off by burning any bridges.

Comment: `I understand that I am my own person and at any time I am free to work where I please...` - Which country are you in?

Answer (score 3):

The only commitment you made was to work for them for the summer, and to give them the chance to check you out (and for you to check them out) so you and they can decide whether this is a good fit for a longer-term job.

You CERTAINLY should look at other companies even if you decide you're most interested in this one -- they may not have an opening for you, or someone else may offer something more interesting, or there may be pay or location differences... Ideally, you'd prefer to be able to choose between several job offers and perhaps play them against each other. ("I really like you guys, but they're offering me $X more -- can you match that, or at least increase your offer?")

Nothing to be embarrassed about. That's the way the world works.